# How many ways are there to distribute 20 different homework problems to ten students if

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

a) there are no restrictions?
b) each student gets two problems?

My wrong attempts:
a)Since there are $2^{20}$ subsets of all possible homework, every student has a chance to get $2^{20}$ types of homework, so in total we have $2^{20}\cdot 2^{20}\cdot ... \cdot 2^{20}=\left(2^{20}\right)^{10}$ possibilities while the right answer is $10^{2^{20}}$. What is wrong in my reasoning?

b)First student has $\dbinom {20}{2}$ ways, second one has again $\dbinom{20}{2}$ and so on. So in total there are $\dbinom {20}{2} \dbinom {20}{2}...\dbinom {20}{2}=\dbinom{20}{2}^{10}$. But textbook says that the right answer is $10^{\binom{20}{2}}$.

I don't want a solution, I need to know what is wrong with mine.

Comment: I cannot find any mistakes in your reasoning (if the students are distinguishable and a problem can be given to more than one student) and would not be surprised if the textbook is wrong.

Comment: It seems that the textbook just confused the base and the power.

Comment: The second one should be $\frac{20!}{(2!)^{10}}$ - each student gets $exactly$ 2 problems.

Comment: How do we know that? The word "exactly" is not written.

Comment: @mihail nvm my original comment I made a wrong assumption.